# How do you use the /tp command?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

When I try to do it in a command block - for a map that I am creating - and put in the coordinates, it asks me to specify which player to perform the command on.  I have already said /tp @p. What more can I do? My command is -

```
/tp @p x / y / z /
```

Comment: Are you saying that something like `/tp @p 1 2 3` doesn't work for you?

Comment: I am confused as well.  Is the command block outputting an error?  I would add that exact error to the question if it is.  I would recommend taking a look [at the wiki](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands#tp) on the tp command, it may help solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Wait a sec., you have to use `tp @p x y z` where x, y and z are, respectively, your x, y and z coordinates. There are no slashes in the command at all: even the one before `tp` isn't necessary.

To see your current coordinates press down the F3 key. If nothing happens also hold down your Fn key while you press F3.

Answer (score 0):

If you have slashes in your current command (between the x y & z) that will throw an error. I always keep the slash at the front of the command even though it's not needed.

Also, are you running a pure vanilla server or are you using something like bukkit/spigot? Some commands need you to specify which "mod/app" should be referenced, for instance when using Essentials.  Some of my `/tp` commands have to be formatted `/minecraft:tp @p x y z` because of this.